# The front part of the object material doesn't render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials

As you can see the front of the castle is laking a material. It is supposed to be a stone wall and you can see it on the sides but for some reason it doesn't render in the front.
Is there a problem with my camera setting or something else. I didn't have this problem before, it just suddenly appeared and I don't know how to get rid of it.
[image]

Here is a render of how it looked before and how it is supposed to look
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, hard to tell, maybe pack the images and share your file (just one object): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the textures, I checked them and they were fine. I also added the .blend file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably bugs because you haven't created a *Normal Map* node between your *Image Texture* and your *Principled BSDF Normal* input socket. Don't forget to set your *Image Texture* to *Non-Color*:

[image]

Comment: It worked. I didn't even know you had to put a Normal Map node there. It worked without it before but it fixed the issue. Thank you